# Java instance field value only changed in method

Tags: java

I made the variables for borderX1-Y2 at the top but I didn't assign them til the paint method. I checked the values inside the method and they are correct, but when I checked them in another method they are 0. How do I get them to keep their values?

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{       
    borderX1 = 20;
    borderY1 = 20;
    borderX2 = getWidth();
    borderY2 = getHeight();

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, borderX2, borderY2);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawRect(borderX1, borderY1, borderX2 - 40, borderY2 - 40);
}
```

heres everything else (I cut the unnecessary bits)

```
public class ShapePanel extends JPanel
{
private int borderX1;
private int borderY1;
private int borderX2;
private int borderY2;

public ShapePanel(){}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    borderX1 = 20;  
    borderY1 = 20;
    borderX2 = getWidth();
    borderY2 = getHeight();

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, borderX2, borderY2);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawRect(borderX1, borderY1, borderX2 - 40, borderY2 - 40);
}

public int getX1()
    {return borderX1;}

public int getY1()
    {return borderY1;}

public int getX2()
    {return borderX2;}

public int getY2()
    {return borderY2;}
}
```

My error is in my returns, they return a value of 0 for all of them

I can initialize the variables like this

```
private int borderX1 = 20;
private int borderY1 = 20;
private int borderX2 = 762;
private int borderY2 = 533;
```

but I want the values of X2 and Y2 to change based on the window size

Comment: What are the types - int/double ? I guess the method you are calling is before the paint() call is made .

Answer (score 0):

Before call the value, you need to initialize value first. That you can do by call `paint(Graphics g)` first or globally initialize the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the paint and the other method with different objects. Please ensure both are same object. If you calling paint method and then the other method with same object the values will be retained.

```
class Sample{
    int borderX1,borderY1,borderX2 ,borderY2 ;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
       borderX1 = 20;
       borderY1 = 20;
       borderX2 = getWidth();
       borderY2 = getHeight();
     }
     public void fun1(Graphics g){

     }
 }

 Sample s1 = new Sample(); 
 s1.paint(Graphics)     borderX1 =20,borderY1=20,borderX2=some width ,borderY2 =some height
 Sample s2 = new Sample();
 s2.fun1();//borderX1=0,borderY1=0,borderX2=0 ,borderY2=0 these values should be 0
```

Comment: I tried this

    ShapePanel border = new ShapePanel();

     public void getBorder()
    {
    border.paint(g);
    borderX1 = border.getX1();
    borderY1 = border.getY1();
    borderX2 = border.getX2();
    borderY2 = border.getY2();
    }

but it says "g cannot be resolved to a variable"